# Generate file TXT file with PHP values issued from mysql selected columns result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I wrote the following to retrieve values from 2 columns WHEN 'PART_EPOCH' value is the lowest.

```
    $next_event = "SELECT 
    PART_ID
    PART_EPOCH
    FROM crud_mysqli
    WHERE PART_EPOCH = (SELECT MIN(PART_EPOCH) FROM crud_mysqli)
    ";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $next_event);
```

- The expected result should return PART_ID and PART_EPOCH values.

How could i send these 2 values into a TXT file with PHP, comma separated and \n at the end of the line ?

I tried to use array(); with no success, TXT file stays empty and chmod does not changed either.

```
    $path = getcwd() . '/test.txt'; 
    $file = fopen($path, "w"); // this will open the file and erase all datas   
    $array = array();

    $array  = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    print_r(array_values($array));  // show result as debug purposes

    fwrite($file, $array);
    fclose($file);

    chmod($file, 0777);
```

Comment: You don't get any errors? You cant write an array with `fwrite`.

Comment: no, i did not get any error or warning.

Comment: Your query should have commas separating the columns. Maybe `fwrite($file, implode(',', $array));` would give you what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `file_put_contents()` php function.

```
$filename ="something.csv";
file_put_contents($filename, serialize($array));
```

Comment: I now get datas in the file if go with your suggested code.  there are extra datas in the file and returned result is not as expected. -- Result should be : "very old, 900633600" but print_r returns : `Array ( [0] => very old [1] => very old )` --- then, the file contains : `a:2:{i:0;s:8:"very old";s:10:"PART_EPOCH";s:8:"very old";}`   My test table is here : [mysql example table](http://s529471052.onlinehome.fr/bs3/crud-sqli/index.php)   Would my mysql command to select value be incorrect?